# Font inside label not working

Tags: visualforce, css, html

I am trying to add a font tag inside label in apex page. on the page i am getting this code in inspect element
[image]

but in UI instead of getting getting text in red color  i am getting the font tag as it is.
[image]

if anyone can help me with this, it would be great..

Comment: infact i tried to change <font> to <b> but it is also not rendering and the same text is shown on page. this is weird..

Comment: can you paste the VF code, atleast the label part of your VF

Comment: We could offer more assistance if you post your actual VF markup. I'm guessing you attempted to put the <font> tag inside a merge expression, which generally doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking from your screenshot,

```
<label id="" onclick="" class=""><font color="red">110-32-8633</font></label>
```

should be changed to

```
<font color="red"><label id="" onclick="" class="">110-32-8633</label></font>
```

**Reason:**

Anything inside of `label` will be displayed as such in browser unless its not escaped(`escape="false"`).

If you want to apply font to the label, surround that label within the `font` tag.

I am talking about the rendered html components only. You have to make changes to your visualforce tags accordingly to get the desired output.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS to achieve your red text, like so:

```
<style>
    .red-label{
        color: red; //might also need !important
    }
</style
...
...
<apex:outputLabel value="{!whatever}" styleClass="red-label" />
```